# iMac Late 2013 Audio Cirrus Logic CS4206 Issues

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, mac

I have just switched from OSX to Xubuntu 14.04 on my iMac Late 2013. I've got everything running smooth, except for my freakin' audio card. It works occasionally for a few minutes and then it just stops. I can't hear anything, but the sound indicator in the sound settings is moving.

I followed every single possible solution on askubuntu and the Ubuntu forums but I couldn't get it to work permanently. The only thing that kinda works for me is force reloading the pulse audio driver. But I gotta do that a couple of times, including logins and log outs to reactive the sound for a few minutes.

I really don't want to give up, and hope you guys can help me figure this one out. I don't want to go back to OSX, I really like my new found freedom!

Let me know if you need more information, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CS4206 Analog [CS4206 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CS4206 Digital [CS4206 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Card: HDA Intel PCH                                 
Chip: Cirrus Logic CS4206
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had many issues with my late 2013 iMac 21.5" as well. The setup which currently works for me is the following:

- Pulseaudio and alsa default settings
- in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, make sure you have the following option

  options snd-hda-intel model=imac27_122

Then, speakers should work out of the box. To fix headphones, I had to use `hda_analyzer.py`, instructions are [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/HDA_Analyzer). I actually had to modify the source a bit to run on my machine, let me know if you need further help with that.

Using hda_analyzer, make sure that you configure card-1 codec-0 as following:
[image]

Sound should then work with both speakers and headphones. The [2] IO is your headphone, the [3] is the speaker. To make the changes permanent, use `exp` to save the changes to a script and call it in the boot process (e.g. in `rc.local`).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's much appreciated! By the way, do you also experience poor sound quality, like an old mono radio with a hissing noise on voices, especially when I turn the volume up?

Comment: What is the `exp` program you referred to?

Comment: sorry, my markup is confusing, Exp refers to the button in the screenshot

Comment: I added the exported Python script from exp to be called from /etc/rc.local.  I placed the exported python script here /usr/sbin/sound.py. In rc.local I removed the -e from #!/bin/sh line. In  /etc/rc.local I put python /usr/sbin/sound.py<br />exit 0 to run it on boot. It seems to work. However, when I check HDA Analyzer, it is not putting a check next to [2] under data. Therefore, if I check next to [2], it works. Any ideas? @noleti Thank you so much for posting this answer! It made me so glad to find it.

Comment: @jbrock Sorry, no idea. I am actually still starting the script by hand every time I reboot (not that often). It also fixes some other stuff, so I need to run it anyways...

Comment: @noleti I actually have been just fine in doing the same thing. I created an alias for it, and it is no big deal to do this once a day for me.

Comment: Here is how to get the audio to work from boot. I linked a pdf because these comments don't have formatting. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B40SH78AyQDxdFl1Y1lYRElFbmM&authuser=0

Comment: After sleeping, the audio would not work. Here is how to run the script on wake.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup You just create a script in /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d that runs the python script that correctly sets the audio.

Answer (score 1):

- You can try uninstalling Pulseaudio and test with  the Alsa audio layer only:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
  sudo apt-get install  gnome-alsamixer
  ```
- Reboot and set the volume with the Gnome Alsa mixer (in the multimedia menu), or `alsamixer` in a terminal:  it could be better as Pulseaudio is  cpu consuming  and not necessary for audio to work.
- If you want to go back to Pulseaudio, look here  :
  [Audio suddenly stopped, pulseaudio reinstall has not helped? (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475450/audio-suddenly-stopped-pulseaudio-reinstall-has-not-helped-14-04solved)

Comment: Holy crap, thanks laugeo! This seems to have fixed my problem for now. Thank you Thank You Thank you, I am so super happy! Oddly enough I tried the Alsa Audio Layer before but it didn't work. Now it does and I'm so thrilled, my computer may look like a Mac, but it actually runs Linux exclusively! I can't thank you enough, you made my day!