# Sound randomly muting in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

PulseAudio or ALSA, I cannot tell which, randomly mutes itself for no reason.  This is EXTREMELY frustrating.  It happens typically when I am playing a game, but can also happen when playing a movie.  I have tried muting my microphone when not using it;  this does nothing.  I have also tried googling for fixes, and have found nothing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: just try updating system

Comment: Kill pulseaudio from terminal on login, then launch it again. Can you post the output from terminal when it mutes? By mutes, do you mean you can unmute it after with the key? Or it stops completely?

Answer (score 1):

- If sounds stops randomly, this is certainly a pulseaudio problem: you can remove Pulseaudio and stay without it in the case you have only one sound device (internal sound card and  no bluetooth or other  ) . At least,removing  it temporarily is a good test for your problem.
- To remove it:

  `sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio`
  `sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer`

  Reboot and set the volume with the Gnome Alsa mixer (in the multimedia menu), or alsamixer in a terminal.

  - If you want to go back to Pulseaudio, look here (from no 4  item):
    [Audio suddenly stopped, pulseaudio reinstall has not helped? (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475450/audio-suddenly-stopped-pulseaudio-reinstall-has-not-helped-14-04solved)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. I didn't really have to use terminal, but it usually depends on your audio source. You can go to audio mixer, click on configuration,an look at the audio source options. Try all of them and see which one works. What can also work is to set the audio source as fallback. Just press the check-mark next to the audio's name. Hope I helped :)