# sound device detected as guest but gone at normal user

Tags: 14.04, soundcard

If I login to my account the sound device is not listed.
If I login as guest everything is there.

I searched before posting and I tried some stuff, but nothing worked yet. Also I couldn't find the same specific problem.

Yesterday everything was working fine and I don't remember messing around with anything.

I'm using 14.04

This is the output of `lspci|grep -i audio`:

```
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

It is the same result as user and under guest session

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix my issue!

1. I looked here:

   [Audio suddenly stopped, pulseaudio reinstall has not helped? (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475450/audio-suddenly-stopped-pulseaudio-reinstall-has-not-helped-14-04solved)
2. `rm -r ~/.config/pulse`
3. Logout/Login

I tried this command before posting here but it was not working. I guess reinstalling `pulseaudio` made the folder appear.

Now everything is working fine