# Why has my audio suddenly stopped working in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, sound

I just installed Ubuntu today. I'm testing everything out and it seems pretty cool so far. There's just one big problem. The audio suddenly stopped working. It worked just fine when I first installed the system, but it has stopped for no reason that I can determine.

I don't like to use proprietary software (though I will if I have to), so I removed these packages: `firmware-crystalhd nvidia-libopencl1-331-updates nvidia-opencl-icd-331-updates`. But they don't appear to be the problem, because reinstalling them didn't fix the problem.

I checked alsamixer, and it looks rather different from what I'm used to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF6iW.png

The "Sound" settings in the system settings aren't too helpful, but here's another screenshot just in case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/or1Cw.png I can't move the slider, and there's no sound devices listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In alsamixer, you see HDMI soundcard, (press <kbd>F6</kbd> to access the 2nd soundcard) .
- If soundcard order has changed, install **pavucontrol** (pulseaudio volume control)  , go to "output device tab" and set 2nd soundcard as default with green button.

Comment: This doesn't work. The "output devices" tab doesn't list any output devices. If I play audio, there's a "dummy output" device, but no sound plays.

Comment: In alsamixer, do you see 2  soundcard pressing F6 ? what is the result of this command `aplay -l``

Comment: Yes, I do see 2 soundcards pressing F6: "HDA Intel HDMI" and "HDA Intel PCH". `$ aplay -l` outputs this: http://privatepaste.com/63ee9d659d

Comment: So alsa layer is ok : try to reset pulseaudio config like http://askubuntu.com/questions/475450/audio-suddenly-stopped-pulseaudio-reinstall-has-not-helped-14-04  ( the first answer)

Comment: Never mind, I gave up and reinstalled the system, and it all works okay.