# No sound output in ubuntu

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My sound is not working couple of days i tried all the things found on internet still it didnt solve my problem. It was working last time but i wasnt able to change the sound level so i re installed the whole alsamixer from that day there is no sound output neither the volume button works.

[image]

Comment: See this: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=241913 and this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/475450/audio-suddenly-stopped-pulseaudio-reinstall-has-not-helped-14-04

Comment: I tried all this but stil didnt work

Comment: U tried with alsamixergui with root Priv?

Comment: ah yes i tried everythng and at last i sold that laptop :D